# What is this hardware inline with the brake cable?

Tags: disc-brake, cable

The brake caliper is an Avid BB7_MTN, but there seems to be some kind of additional element inline with the brake cable. From what I can gather looking at the picture, there's an electric cable coming off.

Does anyone know what it is?

[image]

My WAG (wild-ass-guess) is that it's some kind of force booster. That would be logical because, judging by the wheel, tire, and frame, this is a heavy bike.

Comment: The disk looks kind of 'wild'.

Comment: Is this a bicycle or a motorbike?  IE, does it have pedals, and is it predominantly human-powered?

Comment: Please show a photo of the whole bike, I'm intrigued.

Comment: @JoeK, Criggie, here's where I found the photo: https://forums.mtbr.com/brake-time/definitive-avid-bb7-weight-thread-365630.html#post5182818. The post is ambiguous as to whether it is the poster's bike, or just a photo it found.

Comment: No idea what the extra hardware is for, but I know for sure I wouldn't want to try stopping something as heavy as that appears to be with a BB7

Answer (score 1):

Most ebikes have a brake switch that cuts off the power when the brakes are applied. I would guess this is a switch for the same purpose. Or, it could be triggering a brake light.

Comment: That makes sense as a rationale. Wouldn't that kind of switch be much easier to install on the handlebar lever, though?

Comment: @KennSebesta For motor cut off, I suppose it would depend where the motor controls are located. You're certainly closer to the brake light at the rear end there.

Comment: Yep, looks like a switch to me.

Comment: My wild guess is that this is a south-east Asian Frankenscooter.

Comment: Looks like a fairly standard plunger switch, two wire, so my best guess would be a brake light, alarm or some kind of immobiliser.